# Understanding the completion theorem for metric (vector) spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I am wondering if I have understood the consept of completion of a 
metric/normed space correctly. As I have understood the completion theorem, it is: 
$$\textbf{Completion theorem for metric spaces}$$

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then there exists a metric space $(M,D)$
and a linear injective function $\phi: X\rightarrow M$ such that 
$\overline{\phi(X)}=M$, and such that $d(x,y)=D(\phi(x),\phi(y)) \quad \forall x,y \in X $.

Moreover, this completion $(M,D)$ of $(X,d)$ is unique up to isomorphism. This means that if $(M',D')$ is another metric space with $\gamma:X\rightarrow M'$ a injective linear function satisfying $\overline{\gamma(X)}=M'$ with $d(x,y)=D'(\gamma(x),\gamma(y)) \quad \forall x,y\in X$,

then there also exists a unique bijection $F:M\rightarrow M'$ satisfying:

$1)\quad  (F\circ\phi)(x)=\gamma(x) \quad \forall x\in X$

$2)\quad  D(u,v)=D'(\phi(u),\phi(v)) \quad \forall u,v \in M$

$$\textbf{What i am wondering is:}$$

$1) \quad $Have i stated this theorem correctly?

$2)\quad $In the lecture notes i was handed they required that $X\subset M$. But if this was the case then the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ would per definition not be a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p-adic$ norm, since the rationals in $\mathbb{Q_p}$ are isomorphic but not equal to the rationals in $\mathbb{Q}$ (they are defined in terms of equvialence classes of cauchy sequences. ) Am I mistaken? Must a completion contain the actual set?

$3) \quad $ Is property 2) of the isomorphism $F$ superfluos/wrong?

$4) \quad $ Is  $\mathbb{C}$ not per definiton a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the absolute value? (But $\mathbb{R}$ is)

Comment: You should write "Then there exists a complete metric space $(M,D) \ \ldots$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Almost. See my answer to the third question.
2. No, you are not mistaken. But, since there is an isometry between $X$ and a subspace of $M$, it is natural to see $X$ as a subset of $M$.
3. Yes, it is wrong; it should contain $F$ instead of $\phi$.
4. No, because $\mathbb Q$ is *not* dense in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I ment to write  F instead of phi, but i guess i was a littlebit too quick. I think it's good to get the facts properly on the table before I accept it as true so this really helps :)